# Location for medrash cited by the Chizkuni

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, midrash, yom-kippur, parshat-acharei-mot

The Chizkuni in Parshas Achrei Mos 16:22 writes that the ish iti (the person who would take the goat to har azazel) would not live through the year. He cites from a medrash that the person knew he was going to die that year. Where can this medrash be found that the Chizkuni brings?

Comment: http://dafyomi.co.il/discuss.php?gid=6&daf=66&file=1

Comment: See also here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50092&pgnum=7

Comment: Offhand I think I remember hearing that this is actually a Karaite pshat (!).

Comment: Like the Web page cited by @Fred above, the _Tora Ladaas_ periodical (this year's _Achare_ issue) says that the source of this _midrash_ is unknown.

Comment: This is quoted by the Maharsha in [Chidushei Agadot on Yoma 66b](http://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Yoma.66b?lang=bi) who says:
והשיב ע"פ המדרש והביאו החזקוני איש עתי מזומן למות באותה שנה  
“... and he replies according to the Medrash which is (also) brought by the Chizkuni 'the person for the time who was planned to die in that year ..”

Comment: but which Midrash