How was the Ish iti (Vayikra 16:21) appointed?
I am familiar with the Chizkuni answer who says that according to a Medrash, that Ish iti would die that year.
But does it mean that the Azazel goat bringer knew before I would not make through the year or was it because he was appointed to that task - the fact also, he was offered food and drinks in 10 stations between Jerusalem and the cliff - that he would not make it through the year alive?

I'm not sure if the title is the question, or if your last paragraph is.
I think you mean to ask, did the Ish Iti know he was going to die before he was appointed, or afterward?

Does not Chizkuni say that they would select someone who was supposed to die within a year? This is not something unusual,  I heard stories from my old relatives that some of their parents knew the exact day of their death at least a month ahead.

Also the commentary hints to usage of astrology.

Regardless of the proof offered that someone will die in a particular year, however the "system" works, it is always subject to change.. (See Gemara Brachos 10a , where even a Prophet's knowledge was cancelled because G-d had mercy and extended the man's life. "...King David's tradition: Even if a sharp sword rests upon a person’s neck, he should not prevent himself from praying for mercy.")

From the Maharsha - והשיב ע״פ המדרש והביאו החזקוני איש עתי מזומן למות באותה שנה שהיה ידוע להם ע״י חכמת המזלות

@sam How were they allowed to use astrology?

That is a very good question since we have many sources in chazal that using astrology is prohibited and not even exact ...and furthermore klal yisrael is above mazal...

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82443/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57877/
